# Show specific months in which event will happen PHP

Tags: php, date, events

I need your help. I'm developing a feature for a website using my own CMS. This feature is about events. Im adding events by setting title, start_date and end_date. For ex: Event start_date is 1 january 2020 and end_date is 3 april 2020, how can I receive in a variable the months specifically in which that event will happen: $lasts='january, february, march, april'.

I need in this way because the client has events which lasts up to 5-6 months and I have to show these events in each own box month in front end.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried already? This is achievable using date_diff or DateInterval

Comment: Is a database involved by any chance?

Comment: Voted to close as "too broad". However, this could also be voted out as being "unclear". We cannot answer your question directly, nor will we write code for you by guessing. Please update your question to contain relevant code and what didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help you. Please take a look at DatePeriod https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php

```
// The start date
$begin = new DateTime( '2019-01-01' );
// The end date
$end = new DateTime( '2019-12-31' );
// The period P1M = period 1 month
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
// Get the range as an array
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

$result = [];

// Loop through and create the array in the format you require
foreach($daterange as $date){
    $result[] =  $date->format("M") ;
}
```

`$result` will hold the array of months in the format you require